# MongoDB- Add new field from existing array

Tags: mongodb, python-3.6, pymongo

I am the beginner of the MongoDB

Here I mentioned my database schema

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e72067973c1241068a13647"),
"client_id" : "1001",
"dependent" : [ 
    {
        "dependent_name" : "asdsa",
        "dependent_id" : "DE100"
    }, 
    {
        "dependent_name" : "fdggd",
        "dependent_id" : "DE101"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to add new field based on  **client_id** and **dependent_id**

Here I mentioned My query but cannot able to get my expected result

```
 db.collection.update({"client_id" : "1001","dependent.dependent_id":"DE101"}, {"$push": {"reason":"expired"}})
```

I am **Expected Result** is

```
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5e72067973c1241068a13647"),
"client_id" : "1001",
"dependent" : [ 
    {
        "dependent_name" : "asdsa",
        "dependent_id" : "DE100"
    }, 
    {
        "dependent_name" : "fdggd",
        "dependent_id" : "DE101",
        "reason":"expired"
    }
  ]
}
```

so anyone help me to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.update({"client_id" : "1001","dependent.dependent_id":"DE101"}, 
{$set:
{"dependent.$.reason":"expired"}})
```

Try this it works for me using $

Answer (score 0):

As i am also new to mongodb, as i tried, i can give you suggestion to update whole document or replace it.
both way i tried, and query is as below.
**Update**

```
db.updateColl.update({ 'dependent.dependent_id': 'DE101' },
    {
        $set: {
            "dependent": [
                {
                    "dependent_name": "asdsa",
                    "dependent_id": "DE100"
                },
                {
                    "dependent_name": "fdggd",
                    "dependent_id": "DE101",
                    "reason": "expired"
                }
            ]
        }
    });
```

**Replace**

```
db.updateColl.replaceOne({ 'dependent.dependent_id': 'DE101' }, {
    "dependent": [
        {
            "dependent_name": "asdsa",
            "dependent_id": "DE100"
        },
        {
            "dependent_name": "fdggd",
            "dependent_id": "DE101",
            "reason": "expired"
        }
    ]
})
```

may be it can help you. if any suggestion regarding it wellcome.

Comment: you said update full dependent details but I want to inset one field for existing array

Comment: we can update specific field but it will add at last after dependent node, so output would not matched with yours.